# Windows Media Foundation How to use IMFMediaSink::AddStreamSink

Tags: c++, windows, video, ms-media-foundation

I am implementing sample application using Windows Media Foundation.

I have created one example application as described in below link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703190(v=vs.85).aspx

In the above example I have added two video streams using `MFCreateAggregateSource`.

In the EVR renderer I am able to hear audio of both the videos but I am not able to see only one reference stream video or which is first loaded.

As per the below link,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965265(v=vs.85).aspx

`The EVR media sink initially has one stream sink, which corresponds to the reference stream. To add new stream sinks, call IMFMediaSink::AddStreamSink.`

In my application I am using `MFCreateVideoRendererActivate`.
How can I use `IMFMediaSink::AddStreamSink` to add streams to my EVR.

So that I can see two video stream playing in one renderer.

** Update **

I have modified below example code and added code to add video

```
HRESULT CreateMediaSinkActivate(
    IMFStreamDescriptor *pSourceSD,     // Pointer to the stream descriptor.
    DWORD iStream,
    HWND hVideoWindow,                  // Handle to the video clipping window.
    IMFActivate **ppActivate
)
{
    IMFMediaTypeHandler *pHandler = NULL;
    IMFActivate *pActivate = NULL;

    // Get the media type handler for the stream.
    HRESULT hr = pSourceSD->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pHandler);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the major media type.
    GUID guidMajorType;
    hr = pHandler->GetMajorType(&guidMajorType);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Create an IMFActivate object for the renderer, based on the media type.
    if (MFMediaType_Audio == guidMajorType)
    {
        // Create the audio renderer.
        hr = MFCreateAudioRendererActivate(&pActivate);
    }
    else if (MFMediaType_Video == guidMajorType) // Added this else if case 
    {
        // Create the video renderer.
        hr = MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(hVideoWindow, &pActivate);
        IMFMediaSink* pVideoSink = NULL;
        HRESULT hrMS = pActivate->ActivateObject(IID_IMFMediaSink, (void**)&pVideoSink);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hrMS))
        {
            IMFStreamSink* pStreamSink = NULL;
            hrMS  = pVideoSink->AddStreamSink(iStream, NULL, &pStreamSink);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hrMS))
            {
                DWORD dwID=10;
                hrMS = pStreamSink->GetIdentifier(&dwID);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hrMS))
                {
                    printf("\n%d", dwID);
                    SafeRelease(&pStreamSink);
                }
            }       
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Unknown stream type. 
        hr = E_FAIL;
        // Optionally, you could deselect this stream instead of failing.
    }
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Return IMFActivate pointer to caller.
    *ppActivate = pActivate;
    (*ppActivate)->AddRef();

done:
    SafeRelease(&pHandler);
    SafeRelease(&pActivate);
    return hr;
}
```

But problem is that I am not able to see two video stream in the video window.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (source code)

Comment: @VuVirt: I have updated my question with things that I have added in MS provided example code. I have called `pActivate->ActivateObject` and also then `pVideoSink->AddStreamSink`. As in the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965265(v=vs.85).aspx ---> `The EVR media sink initially has one stream sink, which corresponds to the reference stream. To add new stream sinks, call IMFMediaSink::AddStreamSink` So I have added this code to add one more sync.

Comment: You have to add an output node for each stream in the media sink and connect each video source node to the corresponding output node. Did you do that? However, as I stated in one of your previous questions, you might need a custom media session in order to support multiple video sources to be connected to EVR sink.

Comment: @VuVirt : I have updated code to add output node for both the video streams. But now I am getting error event as "MEDIASINK_FIXED_STREAMS". How to fix this issue.

Comment: It seems that EVR doesn't support multiple streams in Media Foundation then. Or maybe you should use AddStreamSink before resolving the topology (SetTopology).

Comment: Yes I have done that `AddStreamSink` while creating `CreateMediaSinkActivate` for type `else if (MFMediaType_Video == guidMajorType)`. But getting event `MEDIASINK_FIXED_STREAMS`.

Comment: Check this out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/9a4390f7-d99e-44bd-9106-dd58344f850c/how-to-mix-two-streams-in-evr?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment. They also use AddStreamSink. Or maybe you can try GetStreamSinkByIndex(1, ...) instead. Maybe the AddStreamSink(1, ..) will work only after a GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, ...) call.

Comment: Actually you should use MFCreateVideoRenderer (not MFCreateVideoRendererActivate). This way the AddStreamSink(1,..)  should work: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/9cf56aa6-12c6-4ae6-9282-b94b0f02a2ca/media-foundation-using-imfsourcereader-imfmediasink-evr?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment